# cakephp table relation empty

Tags: cakephp, pagination

i would like to know what i'm doing wrong here.

I have this relation

Proprietaire model :

```
var $belongsTo = array(
    'Residence' => array(
        'className' => 'Residence',
        'foreignKey' => 'residence_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
);
```

Residence model

```
var $hasMany = array(
'Proprietaire' => array(
        'className' => 'Proprietaire',
        'foreignKey' => 'residence_id',
        'dependent' => true,
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'exclusive' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'counterQuery' => ''
    )
);
```

in proprietaire i try to get residence name like this

```
<?php
class ProprietairesController extends AppController {

var $name = 'Proprietaires';

   function index() {
     $this->Proprietaire->recursive = 1;
 $this->set('proprietaires', $this->paginate());

 $residences = $this->Proprietaire->Residence->find('list');
 $this->set(compact('residences'));
   }

}
?>
```

but in my proprietaire view

```
    <?php   foreach ($proprietaires as $proprietaire): ?>
        <?= print_r($proprietaire['Residence'])?>
        <tr <?= $this->Cycle->css(array('list-line-odd', 'list-line-even'),true); ?>>
            <td><?php echo $proprietaire['Proprietaire']['nom']; ?>&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="text-align: center;"><?php echo $proprietaire['Proprietaire']['prenom']; ?>&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="text-align: center;"><?php echo $proprietaire['Residence']['nom']; ?>&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="actions">
                <?php echo $this->Html->link(__('Modifier', true), array('action' => 'edit', $proprietaire['Proprietaire']['id'])); ?>
                <?php echo $this->Html->link(__('Supprimer', true), array('action' => 'delete', $proprietaire['Proprietaire']['id']), null, sprintf(__('&Ecirc;tes-vous certain de vouloir supprimer # %s?', true), $proprietaire['Proprietaire']['id'])); ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

the print_r(proprietaire['Residence'] give me a empty array.

```
Array ( ) 1 Array ( ) 1 Array ( ) 1 Array ( ) 1 Array ( ) 1 Array ( ) 1 Array ( ) 1 Array ( ) 1 Array ( ) 1 Array ( ) 1 Array ( ) 1 Array ( ) 1 Array ( ) 1 Array ( ) 1 Array ( ) 1
```

What is bad? My table relation?

thanks for your help.

Comment: what do you get from `pr($residences)`? also, have you looked at the SQL queries cake is generating?

Comment: Are you sure you set up your dabase tables correctly and there is actually related "Residence" data in your tables?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have set the displayField attribute in your Residence Model

```
var $displayField = 'nom';
```

or do the find like so:

```
$residences = $this->Proprietaire->Residence->find('list', array('Residence.id', 'Residence.nom'));
```

else check your queries, set debug level to 2 and add the following in your layout or view

```
<?php echo $this->element('sql_dump'); ?>
```